# Another domain hosting my content

Tags: domains, htaccess, redirects, hacking

I recently created a website of my own after buying domain name from namecheap and hosting it on digitaloceans.

```
http://piyushkhemka.me
```

After googling my own name after a few days, I see this website which is hosting my website on its own domain :

```
gobismarckmandan.org (fixed now)
```

Initially I thought someone was just copying my website, however after a few days, I received a stop and desist letter from them. They thought I hacked their site and used it to host my content.

They are a non-profit website which is understaffed and both of us have no idea why their domain name is pointing to my website.

Any ideas what could have happened?

Anyways, the real question is: to prevent such things from happening again, what should I do? How do I prevent other websites from ever hosting my content?

Do I need to edit .htaccess file? Currently, it looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
Options -Indexes
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 week"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 week"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Do I need to add some options to this file?

Comment: You could both have the same hosting company and they the server configured badly.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller : I am on digital oceans. They aren't. So what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 3):

> fixed now

How was it "fixed"? I can guess... it seems that your website is accessible by both the IP address and the domain name. My guess is that this other website accidentally pointed their domain name at your IP address. Maybe the IP address was similar; although the IP address that their domain now points to is quite different. Either way, this does look like an accidental config error.

You can protect against *this sort of error* with a simple canonical redirect (using mod_rewrite) in `.htaccess`. After the `Options` directive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This basically says... if the site is accessed by anything other than `example.com` (eg. the IP address, or another domain!) then redirect to `example.com`.

> How do I prevent other websites from ever hosting my content?

Well, that's a tricky one. The above directives protect against just that one type of issue - which is probably not how a "hacker" would clone a site anyway (since many sites simply can't be accessed by the IP address and it's easy to thwart).

There are many ways a determined hacker could "clone" a site and host your content. And the more sophisticated are pretty much impossible to protect against preemptively, unfortunately.

> ...subdomains...

If you have additional subdomains then the above "canonical redirect" becomes more complex. One way would be to make an exception for these subdomains as well...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(subdomain1|subdomain2|subdomain3)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When I posted the question, their website had stopped pointing to my website. It seems to be pointing to my website again.

Comment: From where I'm sitting the two domains are currently pointing to different places. If this is something that has only recently been "fixed" (which requires a DNS update) then it can take some time (up to 48 hours) to propagate around the internet. During which time it might appear to be intermittent, depending on how your connection is routed.